# Textwrangler (OS X) -- Simple Text Macro Help Needed

Tags: text, replace

I often, when parsing log/error files, need to replace < and < and > with > in order to be able to efficiently understand what's going on in the files. I know TextWrangler has a macro ability but I can't figure out a efficient way to do this.

Since I have to do it so often I'd love to just have a simple keybinding or menu item to do this simple replace/find all for me.

Anyone know how to do this? ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install VIM then you can use `:%s/a/b/g` to replace all 'a' with 'b'.

You can use MacVim or Cream if the learning curve in the console version is too scary.

You can then alias your substitution then just fire it with a hotkey.